# iScroll: Track Y Coordinate to addClass on Scroll

Tags: plugins, mobile, coordinates, iscroll4

When I log myScroll.y and myScrollPagesY, I get this:

```
var myScroll; 
function loaded() { 
        myScroll = new iScroll('wrapper', { 
                snap: 'div', 
        momentum: false}); 
console.log(myScroll.y); 
console.log(myScroll.pagesY); 
}
```

Output:

0

0, -422, -465

So, the default numerical value is 0, but while I scroll I don't see the number change in the console.

Do I have to somehow incorporate the iScroll refresh(); method to constantly update the Y coordinate?

How would I write an if statement that basically said:

if myScroll.y = a certain number then add the class "selected" to the nav button.

Basically, as you are scrolling down the page I want the nav bar at the top to highlight when you hit a new section.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the onScrollMove-event. Attach a method to this iScroll-property. The first argument is the scrollerobject. Now read the y-value.

```
function onScrollMove(scroller, e) {
  //read scroller.y or scroller.currPageY, or whatever property you want to use :)
};
```